# Logic Implication is relation or operation?

Tags: logic

Jean Blaize Grize (in Logique Moderne Fascicule 1 p:28) has been distinguished between two type of implication : implication as relation among sentences and implication as operation, the former is qualified as preorder relation that is reflexive (a→a) , transitive (if a→b and b→c then a→c) and antisymetric (if a→b and b→a then a↔b) , while the later is described through mathematical proprieties namely ;  commutativity  , associativity …
Is this distinction valid or not?

Comment: the operation is defined on which set?

Comment: Logical implication is just another operator like AND and OR. Like AND and OR, it has a well known truth table.

Comment: Semantic consequences are relations. I don't know if that helps. I know for formulas they are.

Comment: It sounds like your author is doing a bad job distinguishing between $\implies$ and $\vdash$.  Implication is usually intended to be a symbol that manifests as $\vdash a \implies b$ if and only if $a \vdash b$ (some caveats when there are free variables).  If you want to interpret that as a relation, or as a binary combinatorial gate, or as a order, that's up to you.

Comment: I could be wrong but I always thought implication could mean two things. Semantic consequences $\models$, and $\rightarrow$. I do not think syntactic consequence, $\vdash$, would be confused with an implication here. Also, I am not a big fan of using the $\implies$ symbol. My logic book is terrible and uses $\implies$ incorrectly half the time.

Comment: If I was to guess what your textbook is referring to as a relation among setences deals with $\models$ as referring to formulas, particularly WFFs which are relations. The other would just be $\rightarrow$. I do not know if it this would be a relation or not. The definition of a relation deals has $\rightarrow$ in it and to avoid any circular reasoning. So in that case, I would presume the $\rightarrow$ is not a relation.

Comment: I am referring to the $\models$ symbol as a relation here.